# Intellij refresh resources after change on appliacitonserver

Tags: jboss, intellij-idea, refresh

Is there a way to tell Intellij to refresh the resource files (jsf/css) after a change directly without having to "run" the project again?

Answer (score 2):

In the run configuration for the server, on the *Server* tab is the option *On 'update' action*. Set that to "Update Resources" or "Update classes and resources". Alternatively (or additionally) you can set the "On frame deactivation" option to "Update Resources" or "Update classes and resources". IDEA will then update the resources when it loses focus (such as when you go to your browser for example). I tend to find this a better option personally.

If you want to do it manually, you can clock the "Update" button [image] in the Run (or debug) window.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [Autopackage plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=1265). It updates web resources on save operation. I find that this worked better.